# Real http calls fail in e2e karma tests?

Tags: karma-runner, systemjs, e2e-testing

Yea I know Karma is supposed to be for unit tests. However,

1. there's no UI to test because it's a thin Javascript API over a REST-based server
2. a nodeJS test runner won't cut it because we want the tests to run in the browser (the library under test is browser based)
3. we use JSPM/SystemJS.

We could use Protractor. The problem with protractor is that it's designed for testing UIs, so making it work on something w/o a UI seems **hacky**: a) create an entry point file for each feature we want to test that loads all the correct modules b) create tests by accessing these modules in the window global...

Meanwhile... Karma has SystemJS support. It also runs tests in the browser. With karma as the test runner, we can use modules directly in the tests (which is why we need SystemJS support).

However, making real HTTP calls in a karma test fails. We use the fetch API. Endpoints that work in PostMan fail inside of a Karma test... even after disabling CORS (in fetch). So the below fetch call fails:

```
 fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors').then(rslt => rslt.json()) //errors out w/ no status code!
```

Any ideas? An alternate solution to Karma is also fine. A more elegant hack to using Protractor would also work.

Update: another workaround is to tell karma to launch the browser with CORS disabled. The downside to this approach is that we'll need to create a custom launcher for every browser we support.